# will my application be rejected if i use UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as? UIApplication

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

can i use below one ?

```
let app = UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as? UIApplication
```

for app store build instead of

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
```

in my application i was using let app = UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as? UIApplication at some places inside my SDK but after integrating my SDK in notification extension i found compilation issue due UIApplication.shared is unavailable for extension. i replaced UIApplication.shared with UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as? UIApplication. Now i can build my application successfully.

Comment: Hi Amit, Yes you can use it why not. I found this documentation in the apple doc it has no violation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416468-value

Comment: I have doubt as UIApplication.shared is not available in Notification extension if it is not available some how using key path we are trying to achieve. error UIApplication.shared is unavailable for extension using above solution we are trying to violet the rule.